# PHP Getting one or two values from serialised array?

Tags: php, arrays, deserialization

How do I get the groupname value from this array and assign it to a variable??

```
a:4:{s:9:"groupname";s:4:"wewe";s:9:"idCompany";N;s:4:"desc";N;s:6:"active";s:1:"Y";}
```

Comment: Just [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it back to a normal array and fetch what you need from it: `$bar = unserialize($foo); $var = $bar['keyname'];`

Comment: tried that... just get null value... I am trying to run a function after updating wpDatatables

```add_filter ('wpdatatables_after_frontent_edit_row', 'my_hook', 10,3);

 function my_hook($formdata, $rowId, $tableId) {
     $val = unserialize($formdata);
     $sname = $val["groupname"];
     update_user_meta( 1, 'blah', $sname ); 
 }```

Comment: if i just post the array to usermeta I get the values I posted as the question... so the array has data, but i cannot seem to extract a value

Comment: Well, if `$formdata` really is the above serialized string, it should work: https://3v4l.org/5sq2NJ. How did you get the serialized string? Did you check the database or did you dump `$formdata` inside this function? If it was in the database, then WP tends to already unserialize those values for you when you fetch them. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71003423/edit) with more info around how you debugged the data etc (and add the above code to the question as well)

Answer (score 0):

@m.eriksson - You solved it for me thank you ... WP had unserialised the array already ! so just using $sname = $formdata["groupname"]; did the trick! Thank you